# Unable to get steeltoe health actuator endpoints via http

Tags: asp.net-core, steeltoe

I have gone through the release note https://steeltoe.io/reference/reference-release-notes/#2-2-0 and interested to expose /health endpoint via http(I mean outside PCF Apps manager). I have the below settings in appsettings.json

```
{
   "management": {
    "endpoints": {
      "path": "/cloudfoundryapplication",
      "cloudfoundry": {
        "validateCertificates": false
      },
      "health": {
        "showdetails": "always",
        "claim": {
          "type": "health_actuator",
          "value": "see_details"
        }
      }
    }
  } 
}
```

My project has reference to Steeltoe.Management.CloudFoundryCore V2.2.0 and my startup looks like below

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
             // Add health actuator
            services.AddHealthActuator(configuration);
            services.AddCloudFoundryActuators(Configuration);
        }

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app) 

        {
            if (HostingEnvironment.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }

            app.UseCloudFoundryActuators();          

            app.UseHealthChecks();
            app.UseMvc();
        }
```

Now when i tried to invoke the url https://myservice/cloudfoundryapplication/health I am getting an 401 error saying {"security_error":"Authorization header is missing or invalid"}. Any idea what might be wrong here.

Answer (score 2):

Here are the steps you need to access health endpoint outside apps manager when running in cloudfoundry:

1. Do not set `management:endpoints:path` or set it to anything other than /cloudfoundryapplication . Your external endpoint will be available under /actuator/** by default. You can set it to for example management (just not cloudfoundryapplication since apps man uses the route and it is secured).
2. Add your actuators like this: `services.AddCloudFoundryActuators(Configuration, MediaTypeVersion.V2, ActuatorContext.ActuatorAndCloudFoundry);`
   This includes Health actuator so you do not need another AddHealthActuator
3. Use the actuators like this:

   `app.UseCloudFoundryActuators( MediaTypeVersion.V2, ActuatorContext.ActuatorAndCloudFoundry);`
4. To secure it, you can add this config, 
   `"claim": {
         "type": "health_actuator",
         "value": "see_details"
       }`

... you are are expected to provide those in your request. But it looks like you are not. This configuration is a way to secure the endpoint. To see it without security, you can drop that portion of the config. Also the default is show details, so you can drop the config under "health" entirely.

Comment: I tried removing the whole health section from appsettings.json, but still I am getting the same error

Comment: Thanks it got working when I run in PCF, but it is not working when running locally. I am getting below exception during startup "System.InvalidOperationException: Cannot resolve scoped service 'Steeltoe.Management.Endpoint.Health.HealthEndpoint' from root provider. Any idea how to get actuator endpoints working with localhost?

Comment: @Sajan my best guess is this issue: https://github.com/SteeltoeOSS/Management/issues/52. This hasn't made it to our main nuget feed yet, but is available on the dev feed: https://www.myget.org/feed/steeltoedev/package/nuget/Steeltoe.Management.CloudFoundryCore/2.2.0-dev-00412